# How to update field in document sub-array in mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

In a database with these documents

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5448f241e47010336375bb21"),
        "lid" : "Ridali",
        "items" : [
                {
                        "product" : "dogfood",        ,
                        "done" : false
                }
        ],
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5448fc15e47010336375bb23"),
        "lid" : "Qitula",
        "items" : [
                {
                        "product" : "measure kitchen cab",
                        "done" : false,
                        "tags" : [
                                "11x30"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "product" : "radiators",
                        "done" : true
                },
                {
                        "product" : "dogfood",
                        "done" : true
                }                
        ],
}
```

How would I update `dogfood` to `catfood` for `lid:"Qitula"` ? I have tried variations of

```
db.lists.update({lid: "Qitula","items: {$elemMatch: {product: "dogfood"}}},{$set: {"items.product": "catfood"}})
```

without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.lists.update({lid: "Qitula","items.product": "dogfood" }, { $set : { "items.$.product" : "catfood" }})
```

Check documentation - [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up.*S*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)

Answer (score 1):

To update subdocument you need to use the positional [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) operator

```
db.lists.update({
    lid: "Qitula",
    items: {$elemMatch: {product: "dogfood"}}
    }, 
    {$set: {"items.$.product": "catfood"}
})
```